# Many .AutoFilter Criteria which act like OR

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets, one which is used to filter the other.

Using VBA I wish to use AutoFilter such as below:

**Sheet1:**

```
Username, Country, City
User1, America, New York
User2, America, Miami
User3, America, Los Angeles
```

**Sheet2:**

```
Country, City, Contact
America, <>Miami, AllCitiesButMiami@test.com
America, Miami, OnlyMiami@test.com
```

My AutoFilter so far looks like this:

```
With ActiveSheet

    .AutoFilterMode = False 'Reset the filter

    'Set filter values
    With .Range("A1:C1")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=VBA.Array(Country)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=VBA.Array(City)
    End With

    'Set contact to third visible cell
    TheContact = .UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(3)

    .AutoFilterMode = False 'Reset the filter

End With
```

The results while iterating through Sheet1 should be:

Sheet1:Row1(User1): City = New York, TheContact = "AllCitiesButMiami@test.com"

Sheet1:Row2(User2): City = Miami, TheContact = "OnlyMiami@test.com"

Sheet1:Row3(User3): City = Los Angeles, TheContact = "AllCitiesButMiami@test.com"

**Problem:**
I need help with the second Field, "<>Miami" doesn't pick up all cities BUT Miami

Comment: ``<>Miami`` can be used as the criteria in an auto-filter, but searching for it by setting the criteria as ``New York`` will not match ``<>Miami``. In other words, you can use the values from Sheet2 as criteria for an auto-filter on Sheet1 but not the other way around.

Comment: Is it possible to do such a thing as this:
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Miami, OR <>Miami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problems. The <>Miami wasn't being picked up until I used the Criteria "~<>*"

```
....
Dim City
City = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) 'i = current row

'I set the filter to current row data
.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=City

'Check row count (cell count / no. of columns)
rowCount = .Parent.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / 3

'If the row count is < 2, no data, change the filter criteria to find other
If (rowCount < 2) Then
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="~<>*"
End If
....
```